# Does that improper integral converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus

Does the improper integral $$\int_0^\infty |\sin(x)|^x\,dx$$ converge or does the one diverge? Calculations suggest its convergence.

Comment: you should ask whether or not this integral is finite. Otherwise, you should integrate up to $t$ and take the limit $\lim_{t\to \infty}\int_0^tf(x)\, dx$.

Comment: Isn't that precisely what the OP is doing when he asks whether the integral converges or diverges, @Ragnar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually looks like it should diverge, since $$\int_0^{2\pi} |\sin x|^n d x \sim \frac1{\sqrt{n}}.$$ Writing your integral as a sum of integrals from $2\pi n$ to $2\pi(n+1),$ you seem to get a divergent series.

Comment: There you go. I had no idea if it converged or not, but I got to the splitting up the domain of integration, but didn't know how the asymptotic of the main integral in your post behaved. +1

Comment: Could you base that asymptotics or give an accessible link?

Comment: @MarkiyanHirnyk I used mathematica, but integral of power of sin from $0$ to $2\pi$ (you can make it $2n$ to avoid the absolute values) is a beta function (make the substitution $u = \sin x$), so (for $2n$) you get $2\sqrt{\pi}\frac{\Gamma(\frac12 + n)}{n!}.$

Comment: The exponent should be $2\pi n$ instead of $n$.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late, but I think it's a cool different approach.

First of all, note that $|\sin x|$ has period $\pi$. Consider some interval $[(n-1)\pi,n\pi]$ with $n>0$ an integer. Then for  $x\in [(n-1)\pi,n\pi]$, $|\sin x|^{x}\geq|\sin x|^{n\pi}$, because $|\sin x|$ is between $0$ and $1$.

Also note that on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, $|\sin x|\geq \frac{2x}{\pi}$. Thus for any natural number $m$, $|\sin x|^{m\pi}\geq (\frac{2x}{\pi})^{m\pi}$. So $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} |\sin x|^{m\pi}dx\geq\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\frac{2x}{\pi})^{m\pi}dx=\frac{\pi}{2m\pi+2}$.

Finally, about the line $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$, $|\sin x|^{m\pi}$ is symmetric, so $\int_0^{\pi} |\sin x|^{n\pi}=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} |\sin x|^{n\pi}$.

Putting everything together, $\int_0^\infty |\sin x|^x dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^{\pi} |\sin x|^{x+(n-1)\pi}dx\geq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^{\pi} |\sin x|^{n\pi}dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} |\sin x|^{n\pi}dx\geq\sum_{n=1}^\infty2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\frac{2x}{\pi})^{n\pi}dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty2\frac{\pi}{2n\pi+2}\rightarrow\infty$

Comment: How do you find the integral $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\frac{2x}{\pi})^{n\pi}dx $?

Comment: That is just the power rule for integration.

Comment: But the exponent $nx$ also depends on $x$, is not so?

Comment: The exponent is $n\pi$, not $nx$.

Comment: Sorry, it's my oversight.

Answer (score 1):

It also looks to me as if it diverges:

Consider $\displaystyle \int_{x=2^{n-1}\pi}^{2^n\pi} |\sin x|^x dx \ge  \int_{x=2^{n-1}\pi}^{2^n\pi} (\sin x)^{2^n} dx .$

It is possible to do the integrations on the right-hand side into closed forms.  For small $n$ it gives the following values:

```
n    rhs
1    pi / 2
2    3 pi / 4
3    35 pi / 32 
4    6435 pi / 4096 
5    300540195 pi / 134217728
6    916312070471295267 pi / 288230376151711744
```

and so the lower bound is increasing with $n$, and likely to go on doing so, so the sum of the lower bounds will increase to infinity, and so will the the original expression.

Comment: Thank you for the interest to the question. However, you give rather a plausible reasoning than a proof.

Comment: @Markiyan Hirnyk.  Indeed.  But you said *"Calculations suggest its convergence"* and I was offering some calculations which suggest that is not the case